# Jquery Wizard Plugin Ajax Submit - Check Result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Using this Wizard Plugin: [jQuery Formwizard Plugin](http://thecodemine.org)

The problem is that the Form submit is using Ajax. I need to submit it to a specified url (e.g. test.php) and then the wizard needs to check the return (like: error, success, error_2)..

If the response is error it should give a message alert with (for example) an error message.

If the return is success it should give an alert with a success message.

How can I submit it to a specified URL, and how can I check the return?

Answer (score 1):

Hi using this tutorial may be beneficial for your needs [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

As you will see, you'll need to work with xmlhttp.status.

Answer (score 1):

Find the line where the ajax call is made, and You'll found and url, you can change that url, to the one you want.

The other things you want should be handled when you get response in the ajax call.

Also checking the link the previous answer links, will help you a lot.

Comment: Yes it make sense that i need to get the response from the Ajax call. But the question is how?

How can i get the response with the used plugin? Thats the question..

Comment: You should look on the code of the plugin and find how it handles the responses.